# The platform “35729” does not appear to have been added to this project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, building

I get this error while trying to run command

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Error says:
Android Studio project detected
The platform "35729" does not appear to have been added to this project.

Anyone solved this already?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!
I was so unlucky.. Yesterday I updated to Ionic v4

```
ionic@4.10.0
```

This morning there is a newer version which solved the issue

```
ionic@4.10.1
```

I think another possible solution could have been downgrade to

```
ionic@3.20.1
```